# Creating AWS SNS Subscription: Error code: InvalidParameter - Error message: Invalid parameter: TopicArn

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I am following [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-create-subscribe-endpoint-to-topic.html) to subscribe to an Amazon SNS topic.

The purpose of this is to [set up rendering failure event notifications for AWS SES templates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-personalized-email-api.html)

I am getting the following error:

```
    Couldn't create subscription.
Error code: InvalidParameter - Error message: Invalid parameter: TopicArn
```

The region should be correct as it is what I get in the cli when I type `aws configure get region`

The account should also be correct as it is what I get when I type `aws sts get-caller-identity`

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

This error can be caused by several misconfigurations. However, the most likely culprit is that the SNS topic ARN is incorrect. I was getting this error trying to subscribe a lambda to an SNS topic. The cause was that the SNS topic I was subscribing to was inadvertently deleted by another team. Double check the ARN of the SNS topic you are subscribing to. If you have access to the account and topic you can verify it exists by calling:

```
aws sns get-topic-attributes \
--topic-arn "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789012:my-topic"
```

This should return a list of properties for the SNS topic if it exists and you have access.

See the AWS documentation for more details on get-topic-attributes: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sns/get-topic-attributes.html